# How to return value from onDataChange?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a single value in my database, but i find it hard to pass a single string. Here is my code:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS").child(user.getUid()).child("name");

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    editTextName.setText(name);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            String name2 = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
```

How can i access string name outside of this?
I edited my code by it says that

```
    invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Firebase loads data asynchronously. It's best to embrace that and modify your code to deal with it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be a member variable, however it'll be null until the onDataChange method actually assigns it (which could be never if you have no network connection)

Where do you need the value? In a TextView? Just edit the TextView directly from `onDataChange`

Need something more complex, call a separate method from onDataChange and pass in your parameters.

Don't force yourself back into synchronous code

Comment: i want to store it as a string and use it in the other part of the activity

Comment: The error in your question indicates that you never assigned the EditText. I suggest you fix that instead